# How to automatically deselect a checkbox when we select another checkbox in Angular?

Tags: html, angular

I have two check boxes. I should be able to select only one check box at a time.I should not be able to select both the check boxes. Please give me the logic for it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use radio buttons, but anyway:

In HTML bind event by using `(change)="onChange($event)"` on your element.

And in your TS use any of your logic:

```
onChange(e)
{
  if (e.target.id == "firstChoice") {
      this.firstChoice= true;
      this.secondchoice= false;
    }
 else  if (e.target.id == "secondchoice") {
      this.secondchoice= true;
      this.firstChoice= false;
    }
}
```

Or check the example on plnkr: [PLNKR](http://plnkr.co/edit/apSE3cIXA7DIvulBfNGX?p=preview&preview)

Comment: Hi Should I create method name as onChange or onlyOneValue?

Comment: Sorry for the typo, it should be the same name to be linked with event, best of luck

Comment: Hi  Ayoub ELaboussi, I want to set 0 when a check box is unselected and 1 when check box is selected. Please tell me how to do it

Answer (score 1):

Simply use radio buttons or have states for each of them.
So when one checkbox is clicked, you can call a function to unset another checkbox.

Comment: This should be a comment instead of answer.